# Noetherian rings, why commutativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for an answer to why one has to assume commutativity of a ring $R$ in proving some results about Noetherian rings. For example, Let $R$ be a commutative ring; look at the proof(s) of the theorem "if $H$ and $R/H$ are Noetherian, then so is $R$". Where does commutativity comes in?

EDIT

For example, consider the following sketch of a proof. Consider a generic ascending chain of ideals $\{H_i\}_i$ in $R$. We know (by hypothesis) that $\{H_i \cap H\}_i$ is stationary so is $\{(H_i + H)/H\}_i$. Pick the max index that makes both chains stationary (say $m$), then using Dedekind's law for groups starting from $H_i = H_i\cap(H_i+H)$ (note that it is $H \cap H_i = H \cap H_m$ and $H+H_i =H+H_m$ from $m$ on), we finally get that $\{H_i\}_i$ is stationary.

Comment: What book are you studying from? It's possible that the book places emphasis on commutative rings for some reason. Which proof do you want us to "look at"?

Comment: The implication you want holds in noncommutative rings; but if your ring has emphasis on commutative rings, it may not want to bother dealing with noncommutative rings (in which you have the distinct notions of "left-noetherian", "right-noetherian", and "noetherian").

Comment: You should pick a book on noncommutative rings to answer this yourself. The book by Lam or the bible by McConner and Robson will paint a pretty good picture of what the lack of commutativity causes and how it is  handled. That particular theorem you mention does not depend on commutativity but if the book you are reading is a commutative algebra book, then it is unsurprising if it will not mention the more general result —very often that would introduce big complications or simply be impossible; already the elementary study of localizations is considerably more complicated for non-comm. rings.

Comment: Before that thanks
Can you help me about the Noetherian ring

Comment: @asefa If your remark refers to a new question then please post it separately.

Comment: That recommendation should be, of course, "McConnell and Robson."

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Maybe you can convert the comment to an answer, so that it gets removed from the unanswered tab?

Answer (score 0):

*Getting this out of unanswered limbo*

The result you cite *doesn't* require commutativity. Just because a hypothesis is included does not mean it is absolutely necessary.

Contrary to some popular belief, authors are not always interested in expositing with optimized lists of hypotheses.  It depends on the context and audience.  A commutative algebra book will want to reference lots of results that are still true in noncommutative ring theory, but they are not going to waste time pointing out information for a context that is irrelevant to the subject matter at hand.

And sometimes including the extra hypothesis just makes it simpler to prove in the given context, so it is used for that reason.